# Can’t delete Google workspace account ("active Cloud projects"), but lost access to Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I have transferred my domain from Google to iCloud.Thus I cancelled my subscription to Google Workspace and would like to delete the domain and account.

In the admin console however, I cannot delete the account because of active projects: "You have active projects in Google Cloud Platform. You need to delete all GCP projects before you can delete this account.". I followed all guidelines I could find to determine any orphaned project in Cloud Console. There was no project anymore.

Since this morning I am not able to access the cloud console anymore. I get the error "We are sorry, but you have cancelled your subscription to Google Workspace. You will need to re-subscribe to Google Workspace in order to use Google Workspace services like Google Cloud Platform."

It seems I am a bit lost in the Cloud... Who can help me to handle this and ultimately delete the account?

Comment: How? I cannot file a support request because I don’t have a subscription 

Comment: Log in to Workspace. Do you have any users listed? If not create one. Grant that user permissions to Google Cloud Platform. Then login as that user to the Google Cloud Console GUI. Delete the projects. Note: You do not need a paid subscription to add a user to Workspace with GCP permissions. Note: I am not sure what the state of your account is now. You might need either support from Google (subscribe for one user for $6.00) or work with a company that provides Google support. Unless you can create a question with a clearly defined **on-topic** problem, error message, etc. we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the cloud services seemed to be turned off. I don't know how and why, but after enabling it again, the cloud console became available. And I managed to delete the account finally.